# RenderWith passing id doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I tried to pass my data object and object id to the button, it showed I had syntax error which the string produce is weird output.

**Controller**

```
$scope.dtUnitColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null, 'Action').notSortable()
       .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta){
          if(false) return '';
          else {
            return '<div class="btn-group">'
                      + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-manage-unit" type="button" ng-click="openUpdateUnitModal('+data+')" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'
                      + '<button type="button" ng-click="openRemoveUnitModal('+data.id+')" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>'
                    + '</div>';
                }
          })
    ];
```

**HTML Output**

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-manage-unit" type="button" ng-click="openUpdateUnitModal([object Object])" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
   </button>
   <button type="button" ng-click="openRemoveUnitModal(73cc5596-9dc5-11e7-adc6-6c40088df298)" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
   </button>
</div>
```

**Error**

```
> My data is an object.
> Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 29 of the expression [openUpdateUnitModal([object] starting at [{4}].

> My data.id shows error, because is an UUID without string
> Syntax Error: Token 'cec042' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 23 of the expression [openRemoveUnitModal(73cec042-9dc5-11e7-adc6-6c40088df298)] starting at [cec042-9dc5-11e7-adc6-6c40088df298].
```

> When I tried to convert the UUID to string using "openRemoveUnitModal("'+data.id+'")", it will produce an extra equal behind string.
>
> ng-click="openRemoveUnitModal(" 73cec042-9dc5-11e7-adc6-6c40088df298")"=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a string parsing error between the `data.id`. Simply add forward slash to ignore the quote would work.

```
ng-click="openRemoveUnitModal(\''+data.id+'\')"
```

For the data object to be passed, ng-click parameter must be either a value(integer, string or boolean) or variable that defined in the $scope.
Therefore, to pass the data object. Simply create an empty object before and assign the data.id as the array parameter to get the data value.

```
.renderWith(data, type, full, meta){
    $scope.arr[data.id] = data;
    return '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-manage-unit" type="button" 
            ng-click="openUpdateUnitModal(arr[\''+data.id+'\'])" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>'
})
```

**Noted:** In my case, data.id has a string of dash, so forward slash is required otherwise it will produce strange behavior formatting.